# How did Superman know Supergirl was his cousin?

Tags: dc, superman, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

In episode 1 of the TV show, Supergirl, Superman meets Kara when her pod finally reaches Earth.

However Superman was just a baby when they left Krypton, so he would have no memory of Krypton.

I guess they could have left some message in his pod, but Kara was supposed to be the one to protect him so this wouldn't be logical (other than a precautionary measure).

Is there any in-universe explanation of how Superman knew that Kara was is cousin? Or if he didn't know why did he go to her pod when it crashed on Earth?

Comment: In the latest episode, at the Fortress of Solitude, we see that Kal-el (Superman) has extensive records about Krypton and even has a Kryptonian robot servant. Presumably it has provided him with a full background on his family.

Comment: Ah right. I should have caught up before asking my question. If you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: “even has a Kryptonian robot servant” — this show sounds better and better!

Comment: @Richard, really? My question is how did Superman know Kara was his cousin (or if he didn't know why was he at her pod when it landed)? That seems like one question to me. The other question is just my own ponderings on possible answers.

Comment: @Richard, I've removed the bit about the other prisoners. Also question 2 isn't about how he found the pod, just asking why he went to it if he didn't know who Kara was. And I've removed the spoiler tag (I did think it was unnecessary, but better to be safe than sorry).

Comment: @Moogle - I've answered. I'll be honest though, I think the simplest answer is "because she recognised that he's a Kryptonian and told him her identity"

Comment: Well..when a Superman and a Superwoman love each other very much...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the show, we don't really know what Superman knew *before* he opened the pod. I think we can make a few assumptions though.

- He would recognise the pod itself. It's identical to the one he arrived in.

[image]

- He would recognise the crest of the house of El, his family crest.

[image]

- Kara Zor-El would undoubtedly have recognised his crest and **told him** who she was
- Superman has access to an extensive Kryptonian archive along with a Kryptonian information-drone. This database almost certainly have included family photos.

[image]